# How can I open links in the background?

Tags: background, hyperlink

I have very little coding knowledge outside of HTML so I appreciate your time and patience.

I am not looking for someone to write a code for me, just a push in the right direction.

My website works by sending certain customers to a third party website. I have been provided with several links that plant a cookie in the users browser when they click on it.

I would like to make it so that 3 or 4 links open in the background (so that my cookie is planted) but without the user seeing these websites open.

Does anyone have any suggestions to how I would do this? I tried using

```
<div id="follow-links" style="display: none;">
<iframe name="1" src="link1" width="1" height="1">
<iframe name="2" src="link2" width="1" height="1">
<iframe name="3" src="link3" width="1" height="1">
</div>
```

But this didn't seem to work.

I apologize again for my inexperience and appreciate any and all advice no matter how big or small. :)

Comment: That sounds REALLY sinister...

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. It's not sinister at all. We compare prices but our visitors often exit without leaving through our exit link. So we want to plant the cookie early on. It would be made clear in our privacy policy.